# Pattern matching with arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell, matrix

He guys,
I have problems with pattern matching in Haskell. I have a two-dimensional Matrix depicted as an array. 
Here's the code:

```
import Data.Array
type Matrix = Array (Int,Int) Int

doSth :: Matrix -> Matrix
doSth (array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((1,1),0),((1,2),1),((2,1),2),((2,2),3)]) = ...
```

When I execute this code it gives me a parse error in pattern 'array' in line 5. I don't know what the problem is. The argument matrix `(array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((1,1),0),((1,2),1),((2,1),2),((2,2),3)])` should be a correct 2x2 matrix.

Comment: `array ((1,1), (2,2)...` constructs an array, but in `doSth` you need to take a `Matrix` as a parameter and that could be any value chosen by the caller. So `doSth (array ((1, 1), (2, 2)...)` would be valid, but within `doSth` you need to perform the transform on an arbitrary `Matrix`. What should `doSth` calculate?

Comment: `array` without a capital letter? Is this a typo? Furthermore your constructor is called with wrong types...

Comment: You can't pattern match an Array. To pattern match, you need the constructors for the data type, and Array doesn't export its constructors.

Comment: @Lee doSth should calculate the transposed input Matrix. So in the parameter Matrix I have to work with variables a,b,c..? What would be a valid parameter Matrix then? Something like (array ((1,1),(a,b)) (x:xs)) doesn't work.

Comment: For pattern matching, all you can do is match *a* `Matrix` value `m`. Any structure within that value has to be extracted in the body of the function using functions that take `Array` values as arguments.

Comment: @chepner Ah okay so for example if I want to get the Dimension of the Matrix I could use the predefined function bounds m. Thanks, now I know how to solve it :)

Comment: Using advanced Haskell like view patterns and pattern synonyms one could, in principle, define patterns for arrays. the library does not provide these, though -- those extensions are too recent. For the time being, it's better to learn to use arrays through their related library-exported functions.